# How to know whether the object is moving after it is being detected?

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

If my algorithm detects the type of object, how should I know if that object is moving or not? Suppose a person carrying an umbrella. How to know that the umbrella is moving?

I am working on a project where I want to know whether that particular object belongs to the person entering inside the store. I was thinking about the bounding boxes(bb) approach where if the person's bb overlaps with the object's bb. But the problem arises when there are multiple objects with a person.
Here is the code I have written

```
 iou_value = oneObject.intersection_over_union(image,humanRegion_bbs,belongings_bbs)
#iou --intersection over union value

                    if iou_value is not None and iou_value > th_iou: 
                        logger.info("IOU value %f"%iou_value)              
                        logger.info("CURRENT FRAME INDEX  %f "%currentFrameIndex)
                        logger.info("COUNT AT THE MOMENT %f"%count) 
                        if count >2:
                            logger.info("INSIDE THE COUNT LOOP") 
                            logger.info("COUNT inside the if loop %f"%count)
                            oneObject.setBelongings(belongingsList) 
                        count = 0 
                        logger.info("COUNT outside the loop %f"%count)                          
                    else :
                        logger.info("INSIDE THE ELSE LOOP:")
                        b1 = belongingsList.clear()
                        logger.info("value of b1 %s"%b1)
                        oneObject.setBelongings(b1)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/)? My guess is you can make the same algorithm work in your case with some edits

Comment: @RIck M. thanks for the link. I wanted to use the existing bounding boxes from the yolo model

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get your idea. But for tracking the object if it's moving or not. Last time in my project, i detect the object first using cascade OpenCV then applied the Kalman Filter for tracking. Therefore you can track the object detected. About the object if this belong to the person or not. I think overlap is good idea. I think you can check if this overlap long enough, this should be belong to the person as if i understand your problem right.

Comment: thank. you understood the problem right. If the overlap is long enough then the object belongs to the person. I am not sure how to check this condition of how long it has the overlap. This is sort of challenge on the technical front.  I will update my post with the code I have written.

Comment: I don't know how all the object position with the human. But i assume it's in a store with many object with bb. So if the object really attach to that person from the open door ( calculate follow the coordinate) it's belong to the user. 
For others object, my solution is if bb overlap eachother long enough here is if it's overlap more than x frames in video => this should belong to that person

Comment: Thank you very much for your views. Could you please share some resource cascade OpenCV and Kalman Filter. Is there a GitHub repository for your project?  I think there is an issue when there are two or more objects. I have the intersection over union only for two bounding boxes. If there are more bounding boxes I am not sure how to process it.